# Laravel: how to express HAVING COUNT in eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel

How can I express this query in Laravel?

```
SELECT `projects_issues`.* FROM `projects_issues` 

 JOIN `projects_issues_tags` 
    ON `projects_issues_tags`.`issue_id` = `projects_issues`.`id` 

 JOIN `tags` 
    ON (`tags`.`id`  = `projects_issues_tags`.`tag_id`) 

WHERE `project_id` = '1' 
AND `tags`.`tag` IN('tagname1','tagname2')

GROUP BY `projects_issues`.`id` 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `tags`.`tag`) = 2

ORDER BY `projects_issues`.`updated_at` DESC
```

Right now my code is this. 
`

```
$issues = \Project\Issue::with('tags');

        if ($tags || $sort_by != 'updated')
        {
            $issues = $issues
                ->join('projects_issues_tags', 'projects_issues_tags.issue_id', '=', 'projects_issues.id')
                ->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'projects_issues_tags.tag_id');
        }

        $issues = $issues->where('project_id', '=', Project::current()->id);

        if ($tags)
        {
            $tags_collection = explode(',', $tags);
            $tags_amount = count($tags_collection);

            $issues = $issues->where_in('tags.tag', $tags_collection);//->get();
        }

        $issues = $issues
            ->group_by('projects_issues.id')
            ->order_by($sort_by_clause, $sort_order);

        if($tags && $tags_amount>1){
            $issues = $issues->having('count', '=', $tags_amount);
        }

        $issues = $issues->get(array('projects_issues.*'));
```

It returns this error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count' in 'having clause'`

Answer (score 13):

Use `havingRaw`:

```
$issues = $issues->havingRaw("COUNT(DISTINCT `tags`.`tag`) = ".$tags_amount);
```

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::havingRow does not exist

Comment: Just a side note it is good practice to use the parameter binding feature that havingRaw allows as the second parameter if you are passing a variable in that is potentially coming from a user.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer.

In Laravel 3:

```
$issues = $issues->having(DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT `tags`.`tag`)'),'=',$tags_amount);
```

I suspect @voodoo417 answer works for Laravel 4.

Comment: Both work in L4, however this one also is secure - `$tags_amount` is bound in PDO, while in voodoo417's it's not.

Comment: @Jarek Tkaczyk _deczo_  `$tags_amount = count($tags_collection);` secure?

Comment: @voodoo417 Read the comment again - it's not about what you do to make it secure, but what Laravel does for you. Using `havingRaw` simply means, that passed variable won't be bound in PDO statement, period.